# Usage of New.column keyword in mysql before insert trigger

Tags: mysql

I have come across the keyword `new.column` being used in a before insert trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update
    BEFORE INSERT ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET surname = NEW.surname;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I do know `New.surname` would be referring to the last inserted row,but what about `New.surname`,what will it be referring to and no row has been inserted yet?.

Comment: From the docs: `The statement refers to the column as NEW.amount which means “the value of the amount column to be inserted into the new row.”` - that was literally at the beginning of docs. Did you read it?

Comment: I've been to the docs but i was looking for a section on `before insert` only.I have seen that section now.

Comment: How did you conclude that `new` keyword has different behavior based on trigger type? It always behaves the same way, `new` contains the values that are about to be inserted or updated. `old` is available in the `before update` trigger and contains, as the word says, OLD values which are to be overwritten. It's not complicated and you should approach it that way.